# Why is my dropdown menu not showing?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, dropdown

So I've basically tried everything I could think off.  I want to make a drop down menu from an image I'm using. The cursor does manage to become a pointer. I'm really lost to what I've done wrong.

This is the HTML I have right now:

```
<a>

  <img class="dropbtn" id="profile" src="img/icons/Profiel.png" alt="Profiel" width="50px" heigt="50px">

    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </img>
</a>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: none;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

Comment: What happens? Could you post a demo at jsfiddle.net including the js that adds the `show` class?

Comment: Why are you trying to wrap an image round the div close image does not exist `</img>` remove that. Also you you have an empty anchor rapping everything, that should be removed also

Comment: Consider using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

Use below code

```js
$(".dropbtn").click(function() {
  $("#myDropdown").toggleClass("show");
});
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: none;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
a:hover .dropdown-content {display:block}
/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>

  <img class="dropbtn" id="profile" src="img/icons/Profiel.png" alt="Profiel" width="50px" heigt="50px">

    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
 
</a>
```

Comment: The code snippet seems to work fine in here, but when I copy the code my Scout detects an error a line before the code (every time). Do you know why that is?

Comment: show me your link then i will check .... or check have you already added jquery or not

Comment: Yea, I haven't added jQuery. How do I do that? :)

Comment: add jquery in head section or body section but before  $(".dropbtn").click(function() {
  $("#myDropdown").toggleClass("show");
});

Answer (score 0):

Are you open to using jQuery?

You can achieve what you want by simply adding:

```
$(".dropbtn").click(function() {
  $("#myDropdown").toggleClass("open");
});
```

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/XpXoKw)

```js
$(".dropbtn").click(function() {
  $("#myDropdown").toggleClass("open");
});
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: none;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown-content.open {
  display: block;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}


/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>
  <img class="dropbtn" id="profile" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="Profiel" width="50px" height="50px">

  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  </img>
</a>
```

Comment: Simply adding the code doesn't work for me.. But I'm guessing I would have to know how jQuery works then? I've never worked with jQuery.

Comment: You need to include jQuery in your project. You can see from the snippet that I've added it using script tags. Add that line to the head of your html page.

Comment: When you click on the image the jQuery code adds the class .show to the myDropdown. In the css you'll see that .show is styled using display: block. That needs to be in place too.

Comment: The code snippet seems to work fine in here, but when I copy the code my Scout detects an error a line before the code (every time). Do you know why that is?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure to change the dropdowns **CSS** to `display: block;` when the image is clicked?

If not, try this out (**JavaScript**):

```
var trigger = document.getElementById("profile"),
    dropdown = document.getelementById("myDropdown");

trigger.onclick = function(){ // on image click
    dropdown.classList.toggle("active"); // toggle dropdown display
});
```

**CSS**:

or **jQuery** (if you have it referenced within your website):

```
$("#profile").click(function(){ // on image click
    $("#myDropdown").toggleClass("active"); // toggle dropdown display
});
```

Make sure (if you don't already know) to add the above to a `script` tag within your `<head>` or `<body>` tags, inside of your **HTML** `document`!

```
#myDropdown.active{ /* if #myDropdown has class "active" */
    display: block; /* make the dropdown visible */
}
```

Hope this helps! :-)